# Seperate WordPress catagories into sepeat list on seperate pages

Tags: categories

Having issues showing my post in separate list based on category

I have a static home page set my page: "home" and I have the blog set to my page: "Inspiration"

I have 2 main categories "inspiration" and "Portfolio" and those catagories are also the titles of my menu items. So I have Home, Inspiration, and Portfolio. But when I go to portfolio it is just a page not a list of the post in the Portfolio category.

I have no problem editing the code since the whole theme is completely custom I am just not sure what to add to make the portfolio page a blog as well.

You can see the half finished site here. [www.2020mediaonline.com/wordpress](http://www.2020mediaonline.com/wordpress)

I am using WordPress 3.1.1. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i can't able to understand your question,but i guess ,My answer is login as a  Wordpress Admin and select settings->Reading...In There you Select Static Page & Set Front Page and Post page as you want.I think you got Answer.if not means just mention what you want exactly? :)

Comment: I am figuring it out. I had to create a template page and assign my portfolio page to that template. I had already set the front page and blog. What I was trying to achive was having two blogs one for each category. I am going to use the template page and list-category-post plug-in. Thanks for your answer and sorry I was not clear. I am sure I will have plenty more questions.